# how to retrieve tag details in civicrm?

Tags: php, civicrm

Which class is used for retrieving tag details using tag id?
Any body knows the solution please help me. I have to check the tagged element name on the basis of that I have to create one activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pleae check:

```
api/v2/Tag.php
```

A better place for these questions are on [the civicrm forums](http://forum.civicrm.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Since the question was asked, an improved version was released

```
$result = civicrm_api3 ("Tag","get", array ("id"=> $yourid, "sequential"=>1));
```

shoud get you what you want.